# Why can't use " !!document.getElementsByClassName && function(){return document.getElementsByClassName(obj)}" for simplifing codes

Tags: javascript

when I want to check whether **getElementsByClassName** exists for Explorer.
I use under code and it's working well.

```js
function getClass(obj) {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(obj)
  }
}//work well
```

for simplify my codes, I change codes and work well also:

```js
function getClass(obj) {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName) return document.getElementsByClassName(obj);
}//work well
```

But when I write this , it gives some error

```js
function getClass(obj) {
  !!document.getElementsByClassName && (
    return document.getElementsByClassName(obj));
}//work badly
```

There is a error within Chrome.Error message is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return".
for cure this error,I change my codes ,see under:

```js
function getClass(obj) {
  !!document.getElementsByClassName && function() {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(obj)
  };
}
```

BUT,when I use **getClass()**,there console show "undefined".

for description above,

1. I don't know why "&&" used so hard?
2. I want to know is there has some simplify code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this one:

```
function getClass(obj) {
    !!document.getElementsByClassName && ( return document.getElementsByClassName(obj) );
}//work badly
```

You can't use `return` as part of a logic expression.

The problem with this one:

```
function getClass(obj) {
    !!document.getElementsByClassName && function() {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(obj)
    };
}
```

You don't actually `return` anything, you just create an anonymous function that is not assigned to anything, so the default `undefined` is always returned.

You could do something like this by putting `return` before the logic conditions.

```
function getClass(obj) {
    return !!document.getElementsByClassName && document.getElementsByClassName(obj);
}
```

Honestly though, these short circuit tricks really aren't simpler, and I would recommend just using option 1 or perhaps the ternary operator.

```
function getClass(obj) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName ?
        document.getElementsByClassName(obj) :
        null;
}
```

Comment: This is in addition to the fact that functionally, even after the "fix" it does not do what it is supposed to do if `getElementsByClassName` is not available.